# Parrot AR Drone 2.0 full battery shows as empty

Tags: quadcopters, batteries

A friend of mine gave me a Parrot AR Drone 2 that had been lying unused for a number of years. It was in working condition when he last used it. I had also flown it then.

When I got the drone, the batteries were dead so I bought new ones from [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Maximalpower-for-Parrot-AR-Drone-2-0-1-0-Battery-1500mAh-Lithium-Polymer-Replacement-Battery-1-Battery/986409692).

I charged them overnight but when I plug them in, the app on my phone show the charge going from 100% to 0% in about 15 seconds of flight. Testing with a multimeter, battery shows 12V DC charge.

I recharged the batteries 3 or 4 times and got the same result.

What could be wrong?